# Javascript update twitter Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter

I am working on creating a random quote generator. I have it mostly finished using quotesondesign.com's api, but the final thing I need to do is make the twitter button update to the new Quote when I click the "New Quote" button. But it wont change and I'm not sure why.

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 
  //get Quote And call to update twitter Button
  $.getJSON("https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=", function(a) { 
    $("#quote-content").html(a[0].content); 
    $("#quote-title").text(a[0].title);
    updateTweet(a);
  });

  //new Quote and update Twitter
  $('#newButton').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax( {
      url: 'https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=',
      success: function(a) {
        $('#quote-content').html(a[0].content);
        $('#quote-title').text(a[0].title);
        updateTweet(a);
      },
      cache: false
    });
  });

  //update twitter button function
  function updateTweet(a) {
    var thisQuote = a[0].content.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
    var thisQuoteTitle = a[0].title;
    $(".twitter-share-button").attr("href", "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + thisQuote + "- " + thisQuoteTitle);
  }
});
```

Here is my codepen where I am working on this: https://codepen.io/Uberche/pen/RLbjbp

I realize it's ugly and not properly set up, just trying to get the functionality working before doing altering the style and such. Any help would be appreciated. Sorry if this is some silly thing I forgot to include, still learning javascript and forget things a lot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the iframe from the page, append a new `<a>` element with the values you want to use in your tweet, then call `twttr.widgets.load()`.

Make your code like below (tested and confirmed in your codepen):

```
// New Quote and Update Twitter
$('#newButton').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax(
    'https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=',
    {
      success: function(a) {
        $('#quote-title').text(a[0].title);
        $('#quote-content').html(a[0].content);
        updateTweet(a);
      },
      cache: false
    }
  );
});

//Twitter Button Update
function updateTweet(a) {
  var thisQuote = a[0].content.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
  var thisQuoteTitle = a[0].title;

  // Remove the iframe
  $('#socialMore iframe').remove();

  // Generate new markup
  $('<a>', {
    class: 'twitter-share-button',
    id: 'tweet_btn',
    href: 'http://twitter.com/intent/tweet',
    'data-text': thisQuote + "- " + thisQuoteTitle
  }).appendTo('#socialMore');

  // Reload the widget
  twttr.widgets.load();
}
```

Comment: Sweet! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Uberche You're welcome! Don't forget that you can mark my answer as the correct answer if you found it helpful. Good luck with your future coding efforts!

Comment: I thought I could, but couldn't figure out how because my brain apparently isn't working so well. How do I go about doing that?

Nevermind, found it.

Answer (score 0):

The twitter link does not have the class ".twitter-share-button"

EDIT: More detail.

In your Codepen, whatever that Twitter widget package you're pulling in takes that link and replaces it with an iframe and several other nested elements. The actual anchor that the user ends up clicking is buried at the bottom , and it does not actually have the twitter-share-button class on it.

Comment: Understood, thanks for the info! Going to look into the end result of what is being built, didn't really think about how that package would be changing the code.